# Async method not executing from within razor component

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a server-side Blazor app, and in 'app.razor' I have:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @(myService.Login())
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <p>Bitte warten...</p>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

This is my service:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    protected readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public MyService(
        HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task Login()
    {
        await httpClient.GetAsync(loginUrl);
    }
}
```

And the service is registered as follows:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>(client => 
{ 
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(someUrl); 
});
```

However, I get the following error on running:

> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult,App.Services.MyService+d__5]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to happen. Doesn't Login() require a UI to get username/password first?

Comment: so what do you do after you await httpClient.GetAsync(loginUrl); ? do you need to read the return value ? or validate anything ? just wondering !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots...

This is how `NotAuthorized` should look like:

```
 <NotAuthorized>
                @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
 </NotAuthorized>
```

In the if clause you check if the user is authenticated. If not you redirect him to the `RedirectToLogin` component. You do not call a service method here.

In the else clause you display a message... This is done because a user can be authenticated, but he's still not authorized to access a resource.

### RedirectToLogin.razor

```
@inject myService myService

Put here html elements to gather the users' credentials with a "Login" 
button, which when clicked, calls myService.Login() method to autenticate the 
user.

@code
{
    // Note: this code sample demonstrate how to login a user when you use 
    // Asp.Net Core Identity. It is not clear what identity system are you using

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ReturnUrl = "~/" + ReturnUrl;
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl= 
                                          {ReturnUrl}", forceLoad:true);
    }

}
```

Note: This expression: `@(myService.Login())` is evaluated to `System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult` which causes the error. You should use `return await httpClient.GetAsync(loginUrl); instead`